# How to retrieve table values row by row instead of column by column

Tags: c++, sqlite

So I have a table called users which looks like this:

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sid | 25 |
| 2 | jack | 40 |

And I'm trying to get the values in order by row:

```
1
sid
25

2
jack
40
```

But I end up with this result instead:

```
1
2
sid
jack
25
40
```

Here is a snippet my code:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> Sqlite3::get_rows(const std::string& command) {
    if(!handle) throw std::runtime_error("database is not connected");
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::string> values = {};
    // Prepare (compile) statement
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle, command.c_str(), -1, &stmt, nullptr) != SQLITE_OK) {
        neroshop::print("sqlite3_prepare_v2: " + std::string(sqlite3_errmsg(handle)), 1);
        return {};
    }
    // Check whether the prepared statement returns no data (for example an UPDATE)
    if(sqlite3_column_count(stmt) == 0) {
        neroshop::print("No data found. Be sure to use an appropriate SELECT statement", 1);
        return {};
    }
    
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sqlite3_column_count(stmt); i++) {
        while((result = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            std::cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i) << std::endl;
            values.push_back(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i)));
        }
    }

    if(result != SQLITE_DONE) {
        neroshop::print("sqlite3_step: " + std::string(sqlite3_errmsg(handle)), 1);
    }
    
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    
    return values;
}
```

I've used PostgreSQL before and it has a function for retrieving table values row by row (PQgetvalue(result, row_index, column_index)). Does sqlite have something similar or am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: your outer loop should surely be iterating over rows, not columns

Comment: That should only be giving you 1 and 2, no other values, because after those `sqlite3_step()`is done and won't step through all the rows again for the other columns...

Comment: @Shawn I think you're right Shawn. Do you know of another way around this?

Comment: What Neil said. Your loops are the wrong way around.